# How to visualize pgrouting result?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, pgrouting, query, visualisation

So I use this query

```
            SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost FROM pgr_dijkstra('
            SELECT gid AS id,
                     source::integer,
                     target::integer,
                     st_length(geom) AS cost
                    FROM leoforia',
            30, 40, false, false) ;
```

and as a result I get a table but when I try to open it in QGIS it says that table has no geometry. How to create geometry and generally visualize my result in OpenLayers?

Comment: What output do you get? For similar task I used a table with lines between each point that contained fields 'to' and 'from' and fetched geometry from that table based on the routing nodes output.

Comment: You can use ST_MakeLine to join up the nodes with order by seq, assuming that the nodes map to some actual geometries.

Comment: @JohnBarça My friend what do you mean by actual geometries?

Comment: @SS_Rebelious I get nodes teh esge(aka connectors of nodes , cost and the sequence they are connected. what could I use?

Comment: The nodes that you input and output are points in a graph. If these nodes map to a real world, x, y, which you can make a Postgis point from, then you can use ST_MakeLine to join them up.

Comment: aha! nice ! ok I get it so if the results are real life coordinates I use make line to connect them ok thanks!

Comment: Yes, I have posted a possible solution.

Comment: I think it's really time to do the pgRouting workshop: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html I think I have even mentioned it already to some of your other question(s). PRetty much any of your questions is explained there.

Comment: I have totally checked it. Thanks for mentioning it again. For people like me who dont know much of sql it is not soooo usefull. I am not saying that the workshop is not good, it is perfect,but not for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the geometry by joining your query result's id2/edge with your layers's geometry ID (gid):

```
SELECT s.seq, s.node, s.edge, s.cost,
b.gid, b.geom
FROM
(
            SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost FROM pgr_dijkstra('
            SELECT gid AS id,
                     source::integer,
                     target::integer,
                     st_length(geom) AS cost
                    FROM leoforia',
            30, 40, false, false) 
) s
LEFT JOIN leoforia b
ON (b.gid = s.edge)
```

That way, you'll get geometry column which could be fetched and pushed to OpenLayer's vector layer.

Comment: guys if I change the source and target param values, the query wont work.do you know what is wrong? roads is a table extracted from an osm shapefile.

Comment: Is that related with this issue? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121265/pgrouting-2-0-shortest-path-with-pgr-dijkstra-returns-an-empty-result

Answer (score 1):

Following the 2nd example from [ST_MakeLine](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html), you could join the nodes from your routing output, to nodes representing a Postgis point, and use this to create a line, something like:

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(gm.the_geom ORDER BY rt.seq) As route_geom
FROM route rt inner join geometry gm on rt.node = gm.node ;
```

where route is the output from pgRouting and geometry is a table of Points and associated nodes that you use to join the two tables.

Comment: my friend can what is gm and rm? ( gm.the_geom and rt.seq)

Comment: rt is an alias for your route output table, seq, node, etc and gm is an alias for a geometry table containing node, geom, where geom is a Postgis Point. It just makes the query easier to write.